# django with dynamic country state and city selection field in template

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want a country, state, and city selection field in my HTML.

I want to use Django forms for dynamically changing state list if I change the country.

and also require Django form validation.

for example

[image]

how can I achieve this with Django forms and models?

Comment: Dynamic HTML forms have to be implemented in  Java Script.

Comment: you can use https://www.cssscript.com/generic-country-state-dropdown-list-countries-js/ for an easy implementation in html